Generic type on variable declaration
I have a higher-order function that returns a generically typed function, such as the following:
function generator<B>() {
  return (b: B) => b
}

// typeof getB = (b: unknown) => unknown
const getB = generator()

getB("hello") // this works
getB(1142) // this works

playground
How can I set the generic on type of getB in this case? For instance, something like the following:
const getB<T> = generator<T>()

// typeof getNumber = (b: number) => number
const getNumber = getB<number>

getNumber("hello") // this errors
getNumber(1142) // this works

// typeof getString = (b: string) => string
const getString = getB<string>

getString("hello") // this works
getString(1142) // this errors


Note: I realize you could explicitly set the type of getB using const getB: <T>(b: T) => T = generator(), but the actual types I'm using are complex enough that doing that solution would make things fragile.

you can just: const getNumber = generator<number>()

Oh good point, realized I overly simplified my question and asked the wrong one. Updating.

Updated. TLDR I'd like to set the generic on getB, such as const getB<T> = generator<T>().

There's no way to do this purely in the type system. You could write a higher order function to give you this type of manipulation, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

If you want the function returned by generator to infer types, you'll probably need to update its definition by moving type parameters "lower" into the definition. Something like this.
function generator() {
    return function<B>(b: B) {
        return b;
    }
}

playground link
If you need the type parameter at the outer level, you could try something like this:
function generator<A extends string>() {
  return function <B extends A = A>(b: B) {
    return b;
  }
}

playground link
notice that getB(1142) now has an error.
But TypeScript type parameters are tricky, and depending on the complexity of your function, you may need to refactor more significantly to get a solution you like.
